# Belgian Visa Follow up

Tags: visas, study, belgium, application-status, iranian-citizens

I have filed a visa application for Belgium 9 Months ago. Despite this prolonged time, my application's answer is still pending. I even filed a complaint with SPF Interiour against Immigration Office, but they did nothing (just explanations). Would you please help me how can I urge them for an answer after all this time?
I really need your help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did you apply and what is your citizenship? What explanations did you get from SPF Interiour?

Comment: I am Iranian. They told me the decision is not yet taken, just this. I am looking for a way to somehow make them answer faster.

Comment: I doubt there’s much a private individual can do. Your best option is probably to consult an Immigration lawyer for advice

Comment: Thank you very much. I think it costs a lot, but I will try it.